# How to change app (.exe) icon in compose desktop using intellij idea?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I am learning compose multiplatform and currently exploring compose for desktop.

I am creating a distributable .exe but the icon is default kotlin and not the one used as tray icon or Window icon.

Here is what it looks like: [Github discussion](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/2462)

I want to replace that icon with my custom one.

I have already tried [this](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/519436/i-want-to-change-the-icon-for-for-my-compose-desktop-app-but) but it doesn't work.

Comment: I downgraded JDK and now it works.